# Searched for how to CONCATENATE several parts to one SELECT using IN and OUT parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to make one Stored Procedure for MYSQL. Have several input parameters that can change how the complete SELECT that I want to use should be. The parameters can be empty. Keeps getting error (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 58), and are not able to find out why. Can someone please help me!

```
            DELIMITER //
            CREATE PROCEDURE SeDeNa(IN qfrom DATE, IN qtom DATE, IN qofrom DATE,  IN qotom DATE, IN qthc TEXT(12), IN qgr INT(12), IN qde INT(12), IN qpt INT(12), IN xc_s TEXT(36), OUT lnm TEXT(128))
            BEGIN
            DECLARE campaign TEXT(100);
                DECLARE bdate DATE; 
                DECLARE csq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE tsq TEXT(200);
                DECLARE fsq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE ttsq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE otsq TEXT(200);
                DECLARE gsq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE dsq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE ptsq TEXT(100);
                DECLARE sqlQuery TEXT(1500);
                    SET bdate = 2015-01-01;

            IF qthc = "R46" THEN 
                SET csq = "AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` <> ''";
            ELSE IF qthc = "V76" THEN 
                SET csq = "AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` <> ''";
            ELSE IF xc_s <> "" THEN  
                    SET csq = CONCAT("AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` LIKE '%",xc_s, "%' ");
            END IF;

            IF qfrom = "" THEN SET fsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", basedate, "' ");
            ELSE SET fsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", qfrom, "' ");
            END IF;

            IF qtom = "" THEN SET ttsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", DATE, "' ");
            ELSE SET ttsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", qtom, "' ");
            END IF;

            IF fsq <> "" THEN SET tsq = CONCAT(fsq, ttsq);
            END IF;

            IF qofrom <> "" THEN 
                IF qotom <> "" THEN
                    SET otsq = CONCAT(" AND (`pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", qofrom, "' AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", qotom, "') ");
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF qgr <> "" THEN SET gsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_gr` = '", qgr, "'");
            ELSE 
                IF qde <> "" THEN SET dsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_nr` = '", qde, "' ");
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF qpt <> "" THEN SET ptsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`p_id` IN (", qpt, ") ");
            END IF;


            SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("SELECT DISTINCT `pl_stat`.`d_nme` FROM `pl_stat` WHERE `pl_stat`.`p_qty` > 0 AND `pl_stat`.`p_type` = 1", tsq, csq, dsq, groupsql, " ORDER BY `pl_stat`.`p_sort` ASC ");

               PREPARE sqlQuery FROM @sqlstring;

               EXECUTE sqlQuery;


            END //
            DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else if should become elseif

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SeDeNa(IN qfrom DATE, IN qtom DATE, IN qofrom DATE,  IN qotom DATE, IN qthc TEXT(12), IN qgr INT(12), IN qde INT(12), IN qpt INT(12), IN xc_s TEXT(36), OUT lnm TEXT(128))
BEGIN
    DECLARE campaign TEXT(100);
    DECLARE bdate DATE; 
    DECLARE csq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE tsq TEXT(200);
    DECLARE fsq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE ttsq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE otsq TEXT(200);
    DECLARE gsq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE dsq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE ptsq TEXT(100);
    DECLARE sqlQuery TEXT(1500);
    SET bdate = 2015-01-01;

    IF qthc = "R46" THEN 
        SET csq = "AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` <> ''";
    ELSEIF qthc = "V76" THEN 
        SET csq = "AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` <> ''";
    ELSEIF xc_s <> "" THEN  
            SET csq = CONCAT("AND `pl_stat`.`c_code` LIKE '%",xc_s, "%' ");
    END IF;

    IF qfrom = "" THEN SET fsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", basedate, "' ");
    ELSE SET fsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", qfrom, "' ");
    END IF;

    IF qtom = "" THEN SET ttsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", DATE, "' ");
    ELSE SET ttsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", qtom, "' ");
    END IF;

    IF fsq <> "" THEN SET tsq = CONCAT(fsq, ttsq);
    END IF;

    IF qofrom <> "" THEN 
        IF qotom <> "" THEN
            SET otsq = CONCAT(" AND (`pl_stat`.`d_date` >= '", qofrom, "' AND `pl_stat`.`d_date` <= '", qotom, "') ");
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF qgr <> "" THEN SET gsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_gr` = '", qgr, "'");
    ELSE 
        IF qde <> "" THEN SET dsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`d_nr` = '", qde, "' ");
        END IF;
    END IF;


    IF qpt <> "" THEN SET ptsq = CONCAT(" AND `pl_stat`.`p_id` IN (", qpt, ") ");
    END IF;


    SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("SELECT DISTINCT `pl_stat`.`d_nme` FROM `pl_stat` WHERE `pl_stat`.`p_qty` > 0 AND `pl_stat`.`p_type` = 1", tsq, csq, dsq, groupsql, " ORDER BY `pl_stat`.`p_sort` ASC ");

    PREPARE sqlQuery FROM @sqlstring;

    EXECUTE sqlQuery;


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The above runs without a 1064 Syntax Error

Comment: welcome to the stack. glad that worked. Please mark my Answer with the green check mark to alert others it is solved (if it is)