# Converting SQL Query to Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I convert this to a stored procedure?

```
select 
employee_name,
SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'CEL', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as cell,
SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'NDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as ndd,
SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'IDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as idd,
SUM(cdr_charge_amount) as total
from cdr_employees
```

I am not familiar with storedprocs.

Comment: what's your flavor of SQL? MS-SQL , Oracle ? etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out *why* you need a stored proc here, and where your inputted/outputted data goes. But Here's the framework for a stored-proc, in MySQL :

```
     drop procedure if exists simpleproc;

     DELIMITER //
      CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc ()
      BEGIN

      select 
      employee_name,
      SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'CEL', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as cell,
      SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'NDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as ndd,
      SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'IDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as idd,
      SUM(cdr_charge_amount) as total
      from cdr_employees;

      END//
     DELIMITER;
```

### Test it

```
call simpleproc();
```

Please see this example for a good reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650323/763029

[Stored procedure video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCt6IZCZTxc)
[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: There is an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
      select 
      employee_name,
      SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'CEL'' at line 2

Comment: Has error again: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
      BEGIN
      select 
      employee_name,
      SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code' at line 1

Comment: I need to convert the query above to storedproc because the query does not work in table adapter. @coffee

Comment: Yehey! Appreciate your help. Thanks so much! @Coffee

Comment: I removed the `INTO` from the query , it's now just `from cdr_employees`

Comment: I see. Error again :(

Comment: what are you seriously trying to do Coffee with the parameter, jam all the output into a variable lol.

Comment: @Drew - I thought I need to use that to call the stored procedure. It returns the output into the VARCHAR ... or am I thinking through this wrong?

Comment: just dont do the variable at all. Let it ALL fall out of the stored proc

Comment: there was no mention of a need for a variable

Comment: @Drew - Ok gotcha, fair enough !

Comment: there, i added some do-hickies after the stored proc name

Comment: Guys. Pls see my answer post. Any suggestion?

Comment: I does not have error. But I does not run. -- (0 row(s)affected,1 warning(s))
(0 ms taken)

Comment: did you try the `call simpleproc();` command that Drew added ?

Comment: Does not exist. @Coffee

Comment: @Drew - what thinks you sir ?   Re: `Does not exist. `

Comment: it expects that. that is the way you do it. If it exists, it drops it. If it does not exist, nothing to drop. Either way, you then run what follows. That is how you do it in a script.

Comment: Remember that this is something you do a few times (maybe once). Then that is it. Til ya have to tweak it again, maybe a year later

Answer (score 0):

If Sql Server you can use the CASE keyword.

```
select 
employee_name,
CASE WHEN cdr_call_type_code = 'CEL' THEN SUM(cdr_call_type_code) ELSE 0 AS cell,
...from cdr_employees
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this syntax works..

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lcs_rdb`.`sp_CostCenterReport`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_CostCenterReport`()
BEGIN
        SET @sql = CONCAT("
            select 
            employee_name,
            SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'CEL', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as cell,
            SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'NDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as ndd,
            SUM(IF(cdr_call_type_code = 'IDD', cdr_charge_amount, 0)) as idd,
            SUM(cdr_charge_amount) as total
            from cdr_employees
            ");
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes. It runs. But I need to know how to set where clause in the code behind :( @Coffee

Comment: what do you want for a where clause? I am waiting to see why you need a `PREPARE` ... because right now this is complete overkill

Comment: as of now, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: Here is the reason. Prepared Statements inside of a stored proc are for the purpose of dynamically putting a query together. Through changes presented to it (like this one I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/33556682/ ). These changes can be in data found inside queries in the inside of the proc such as queries into parameters. Or they can be parameters passed in

Comment: You have none of these. So you just made your proc unnecessarily double complicated.

Comment: So, in other words, if the query does not need to be put together dynamically, you don't do it the way you just did. You just do it, like @Coffee did.